# NSIS Eclipse plugin not working

Tags: java, eclipse, nsis

I want to use the NSIS eclipse plugin under eclipse indigo and windows 7.
I installed the NSIS plugin in eclipse with the eclipse plugin manager.

When I click File->New->Other->EclipseNSIS_Script I get the error:

> EclipseNSIS only supports the following VMs on Windows 7:
>   1. Sun Version 1.4x, 5.x, 6.x
>   2. IBM Version 1.4x
>   3. BEA Version 1.4x and 1.5x

After that I get another error message:

> Problem opening wizard.The selected wizard could not be started. 
>   Plug-in net.sf.eclipsensis was unable to load class
>   net.sf.eclipsensis.wizard.NSISScriptWizard. An error occurred while
>   automatically activating bundle net.sf.eclipsensis (755).

I changed the Java version in Eclipse to java5 and java 6.
I set the Java version in the System Path variables.
nothing worked. I still get the same error.

any ideas?

Comment: I am having the same problem with Kepler Eclipse and NSIS.

Comment: There is this reported issue http://sourceforge.net/p/eclipsensis/bugs/74/

Comment: Similar problem on Windows 10 (platform not supported), I just gave up, edit with note block and run with makensisw.exe when I need to compile

Answer (score 3):

I had problems getting Java to behave nicely with Eclipse and the NSIS plugin but the solution in the end was to use Sun v6 and specify the path to the javaw.exe using the -vm argument in the eclipse.ini file (which is in the same folder as eclipse.exe).

This is what my eclipse.ini looks like:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:/Progra~1/Java/jre6/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
```

Comment: I have java 7 and this isn't working. Is it possible to run javaws in a version 6 mode or something ?

Comment: Anyone know how to get this plugin to work in Windows 10? I get an error message from the plugin that it only goes up to Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar kinds of problems with Eclipse Kepler using EclipseNSIS.

Finally I ran the NSIS installer from [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System (NSIS) download web site](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Download) after closing Eclipse and when I reopened Eclipse and double clicked on the .nsi script file, it opened up in the EclipseNSIS editor window.

I am still having problems with the compile button and compile menu item of EclipseNSIS however what I am doing is to right click on the .nsi file to bring up a popup menu and then select the "Run As" menu option which has a "NSIS Script" option.  By doing the "Run As" I am able to compile the .nsi file.

I am using Windows 7 64 bit OS.

**Edit Jun-04-2015**

I revisited this answer and saw the answer from Rodrigo below so thought to take another look at this problem which has been on the back burner.

I started up Eclipse and the first thing I did was to run the updater to update Eclipse. Next I used the Install dialog available from the Help menu to check for GEF at URL `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases` and did that install. Finally I did an update using the NSIS Update Wizard which is available from the Help menu.

After this procedure the Run tool will now run my .nsi script to create an installer and it does appear to create an installer however there is an error message at the end:

```
Updating NSIS markers has encountered a problem
org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor cannot be cast to net.sf.eclipsensis.editor.NSISEditor
```

The details shows the following text:

```
org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor cannot be cast to net.sf.eclipsensis.editor.NSISEditor
org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor cannot be cast to net.sf.eclipsensis.editor.NSISEditor
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I have the same problem and i don't know how do? can you help me if you have a solution?

Comment: @GracePii, I have just been doing the "Run As" work around and have not bothered to do anything else.  This is something I will need to tackle however it is not a priority since I have a work around.  One thing I have not done is to update my environment lately.  It may be that it has been fixed and I just do not have an update with the fix.

Comment: Maybe I have resolved the problem just now. My problem was fault of the antivirus. I used the NSIS installer that you suggested. I open the test.nsi using the command "Compile NSI scripts" and I compile it. It creates the installer and it works for me. So I think that I will use this method without trying to fix the eclipse problem. if you find some other solution, also with the Eclipse plugin, help me too. Thanks very much!

Comment: @GracePii, I am glad to hear that you have a solution.  Information Technology seems to have so many bumps and walls to run into that it is nice when you can come up with something that works.  I will do a happy dance to celebrate your victory!

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure you have [Eclipse GEF 3.5](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/download.php?file=/tools/gef/downloads/drops/3.5.1/R200909151220/GEF-runtime-3.5.1.zip) installed too!

Comment: That is the answer to his problem :)
Have tried all they said here too, and none is a solution, but this is!

Comment: I used the Eclipse updater to update Eclipse Kepler, NSIS, and to install GEF using `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/gef/updates/releases` and I now seem to be able to run my NSIS scripts to generate an installer by clicking the `Run` button. However I am still seeing an error of `Updating NSIS markers has encountered a problem` with details saying that `org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor cannot be cast to net.sf.eclipsensis.editor.NSISEditor` however the installation file is generated so that is progress.

Answer (score 1):

I know this an old thread but just to let you all know I've made available a version of EclipseNSIS which compatible with **Eclipse >= 4.18 (2020-12) x86_64** and **Microsoft Windows 10**.

To download it just use this update site in "Eclipse->Help->Install new software...":
**https://apinela.github.io/EclipseNSIS/**

If you want to have a look at the structural refactor that was done on the whole building process using tycho-maven-plugin to *mavenize* the build, be my guest:
https://github.com/apinela/EclipseNSIS/

Answer (score 0):

1. Sun Version 1.4x, 5.x, 6.x
2. IBM Version 1.4x
3. BEA Version 1.4x and 1.5x

Which one is installed which one do you use?

I would recommend you´ll install sun 6.x.

The problem might be that you are using a different JRE!

Comment: I tried sun7x64, sun6x64 and sun5x32. worked with none of them.

Answer (score 0):

The following works on my PC with Win7.x64:

- Installing Eclipse MARS.1 32bit
- Installing [JRE 7.80 32bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html#jre-7u80-oth-JPR) from JAVA Archiv (Oracle-Account was nessesary to create for download)
- Editing the eclipse.ini like decribed above, but you have to detect the right 8.3-directoryname with dir /x. For me is was Progra~2:

  ```
  ...
  openFile
  -vm
  C:/Progra~2/Java/jre7/bin/javaw.exe
  ...
  ```
- copying the files from this http://www.sharksoftware.it/nsispackage.zip to the plugin-folder

Answer (score 0):

install [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Download) and [GEF](http://o7planning.org/web/fe/default/en/document/763947/install-gef-into-eclipse) plugin for your eclipse