# NSIS Eclipse showing an empty error message

Tags: java, deployment, nsis, java-web-start, eclipse-kepler

I've tried multiple times, in the last trial I left almost everything by it's default. But I always get an empty error message in the end and the wizard does not complete.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7613045/897041) but it didn't work. Probably because I hava Java 7 installed ? Is there a way to start javaws in an older version context ? As in running in Java 6 mode or something ?

- How can I fix this ? Or even debug it ?
- Is there an alternative, free and powerful NSIS script wizard ?

Environment

- Eclipse Kepler 4.3
- Windows 7

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this link, works on Kepler SR1

Uninstall the previous NSIS plugin and drop the files(from the link) in eclipse plugin

http://www.sharksoftware.it/nsispackage.zip

http://sourceforge.net/p/eclipsensis/discussion/396972/thread/8b7031bf/#1707

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the file in Filesystem instead of Workspace.

This also happened to me but I was able to change file and it's location and to Finish the wizard.